# Java NullPointerException at jpa.EntityManagerImpl.getActivePersistenceContext

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jpa, eclipselink

I am developing an application using Eclipse IDE, Eclipse-Link, JPA, and MySQL.
During a find operation in the main application I get the following exception from the Data Access layer:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException 
       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.getActivePersistenceContext(EntityManagerImpl.java:1931)
       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionImpl.begin(EntityTransactionImpl.java:93)
       at database.dao.DAO.find(DAO.java:41)   
       at database.facade.FacadeImpl.find(FacadeImpl.java:32)
[...]
```

The Data Access Layer is implemented by `ServerServiceImpl`, which has a `serverFacade` that delegates the operation to `DAO` object:

```
public class ServerServiceImpl extends ServerService {

        private Facade<ServerModelSim> serverFacade;

        public ServerServiceImpl(){
            FacadeFactory facadeFactory = new FacadeFactory();
            serverFacade = facadeFactory.createFacade(ServerModelSim.class);
        }

    @Override
    public ServerModel getById(int id) throws ServiceCenterAccessException {
        return serverFacade.find(id);
    }
}
```

The `DAO find()` is implemented as follows:

```
public T find(int entityID) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        T entity =  em.find(className, entityID);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        return entity;

    }
```

The `Entity Manager (em)` object from DAO is created here:

```
public class FacadeFactory {

    private EntityManager entityManager;


    public FacadeFactory() {
        this.entityManager = DBConnection.connect();
    }

     public <T> Facade<T> createFacade(Class<T> c) {
        return new FacadeImpl<T>(new DAO<T>(entityManager, c));
    }

    public void closeConnection() {
        entityManager.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        entityManager.close();
    }
}


public class DBConnection {
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "todos";
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence
            .createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    private static EntityManager em = null;

    public static EntityManager connect() {
        System.out.println("DBConn Sim");
        if (em == null)
            em = factory.createEntityManager();
        return em;
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help in solving this issue. Thanks!

**UPDATE**
Changing DBConnection class to return a new EntityManager each time seems to solve the problem:

```
public class DBConnection {
    private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "todos2";
    private static EntityManagerFactory factory;

    public static EntityManager connect() {
        System.out.println("CONNECT");
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();
        return em;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make this into a question.  I see a bunch of information, but no question.

Comment: My question would be how to address this problem. Thanks!

Comment: The EntityManager.find method doesn't need to be wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: Thanks, @RobertoLinares! Taking out the transaction resulted in 'Attempting to execute an operation on a closed EntityManagerFactory' and that's how I found the solution.

Comment: @sebi you're welcome. Also remember that if you close your EntityManager, your entities will lose their 'managed' state and you will not be able to update or delete them with another EntityManager unless you re-attach them to its PersistentContext. It is preferable to keep your EntityManager open and alive while you still operate with your entities.

Comment: Yes, @RobertoLinares! I was calling close() on the EM and I forgot it was implemented as singleton.

Comment: @RobertoLinares how do you know whether the `EntityManager` isAlive, and, if not, how do you bring it back?  as per the solution above?

Comment: @Thufir What I do is enclose the EntityManager call in a try block and in the catch I call again the `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PU).createEntityManager()` method.