# JPA connection time out

Tags: java, database, jpa, entitymanager, jdbc-pool

Why does this time-out and become non-responsive?

log:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ cat NetBeansProjects/Legacy/output.log 
[EL Config]: metadata: 2014-09-16 02:03:51.562--ServerSession(18132245)--Thread(Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main])--The access type for the persistent class [class legacy.database.Clients] is set to [FIELD].
[EL Config]: metadata: 2014-09-16 02:03:51.678--ServerSession(18132245)--Thread(Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main])--The alias name for the entity class [class legacy.database.Clients] is being defaulted to: Clients.
[EL Info]: 2014-09-16 02:03:52.487--ServerSession(18132245)--Thread(Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main])--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Fine]: connection: 2014-09-16 02:03:53.762--Thread(Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main])--Detected database platform: org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform
[EL Config]: connection: 2014-09-16 02:03:53.814--ServerSession(18132245)--Connection(17690514)--Thread(Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main])--connecting(DatabaseLogin(
    platform=>MySQLPlatform
    user name=> "jdbc"
    datasource URL=> "jdbc:mysql://ix.bounceme.net:3306/legacy?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
))
[EL Config]: connection: 2014-09-16 02:03:54.683--ServerSession(18132245)--Connection(14590431)--Thread(Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main])--Connected: jdbc:mysql://ix.bounceme.net:3306/legacy?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
    User: jdbc@S0106c8fb2677e8ca.vs.shawcable.net
    Database: MySQL  Version: 5.5.38-0ubuntu0.14.04.1
    Driver: MySQL Connector Java  Version: mysql-connector-java-5.1.28 ( Revision: ${bzr.revision-id} )
[EL Info]: connection: 2014-09-16 02:03:54.984--ServerSession(18132245)--Thread(Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main])--file:/home/thufir/NetBeansProjects/Legacy/dist/Legacy.jar_LegacyDatabasePU login successful
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-09-16 02:05:15.185--ClientSession(10981153)--Connection(14590431)--Thread(Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main])--INSERT INTO legacy.clients (address, city, closer1, closer2, company, confirmation, country, date_cancelled, date_created, date_sold, date_updated, description, email, exterior_color, features, interior_color, interior_type, kilometres, make, mileageType, model, name, notes, opener, payment_method, phone1, phone2, postal, price, province, recording, refunded, reg_fee, status, tax_rate, trim, verifier, year) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [, , , , , , , null, 2014-09-16 02:05:15.044, null, null, , gjkghjkg, , , , , 0, , , , tyuigtyui, , nick, , , , , 0.0, , , 0.0, 0.0, opened1, 0, , , 0]
[EL Fine]: sql: 2014-09-16 02:05:15.327--ClientSession(10981153)--Connection(14590431)--Thread(Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main])--SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()
thufir@dur:~$
```

At worst, it should re-establish a connection to the database, even if it does that slowly.

```
package legacy.database;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

public enum Queries {

    INSTANCE;
    private final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Queries.class.getName());
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("LegacyDatabasePU");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    private EntityManager reconnect() {
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("LegacyDatabasePU");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        log.info("em\t" + em.isOpen());
        return em;
    }

    private List<Clients> findAll() {
        reconnect();
        Query q = em.createQuery("select c from Clients c");
        List<Clients> clients = q.getResultList();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
        return clients;
    }

    public List<Clients> selectByCriteria(Criteria criteria) {
        log.info(criteria.toString());
        reconnect();
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Clients> clientCriteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Clients.class);
        Root<Clients> clientRoot = clientCriteriaQuery.from(Clients.class);
        clientCriteriaQuery.select(clientRoot);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.name), "%" + criteria.getName() + "%"));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.phone1), "%" + criteria.getPhone1() + "%"));
        predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.email), "%" + criteria.getEmail() + "%"));
        if (!criteria.getOpener().equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.opener), "%" + criteria.getOpener() + "%"));
        }
        if (!criteria.getCloser1().equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.closer1), "%" + criteria.getCloser1() + "%"));
        }
        if (!criteria.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("all")) {
            predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(clientRoot.get(Clients_.status), "%" + criteria.getStatus() + "%"));
        }
        clientCriteriaQuery.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        List<Clients> clients = em.createQuery(clientCriteriaQuery).getResultList();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
        return clients;
    }

    public Clients findById(int id) {
        reconnect();
        Clients client = em.find(Clients.class, id);
        em.close();
        emf.close();
        return client;
    }

    public void send(int id) {
        reconnect();
        Clients c = em.find(Clients.class, id);
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        Timestamp t = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        c.setDateUpdated(t.toString());
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }

    private Timestamp stamp() {
        Date d = new Date();
        return new Timestamp(d.getTime());
    }

    public int persistClient(Clients client) {
        reconnect();
        client.setDateCreated(stamp().toString());
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(client);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        log.fine(client.getTrim());
        em.close();
        emf.close();
        return client.getId();
    }

    public int update(Clients newClient) {
        reconnect();
        Clients oldClient = em.find(Clients.class, newClient.getId());
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        oldClient.setAddress(newClient.getAddress());
        oldClient.setCity(newClient.getCity());
        oldClient.setCloser1(newClient.getCloser1());
        oldClient.setCloser2(newClient.getCloser2());
        oldClient.setCountry(newClient.getCountry());
        oldClient.setCompany(newClient.getCompany());
        oldClient.setDateCancelled(newClient.getDateCancelled());
        oldClient.setDateSold(newClient.getDateSold());
        if ((oldClient.getDateCreated().length() < 3) || (oldClient.getDateCreated() == null)) {
            oldClient.setDateCreated(stamp().toString());
        }
        oldClient.setDateUpdated(stamp().toString());
        oldClient.setDescription(newClient.getDescription());
        oldClient.setEmail(newClient.getEmail());
        oldClient.setExteriorColor(newClient.getExteriorColor());
        oldClient.setFeatures(newClient.getFeatures());
        //no id set
        oldClient.setInteriorColor(newClient.getInteriorColor());
        oldClient.setInteriorType(newClient.getInteriorType());
        oldClient.setKilometres(newClient.getKilometres());
        oldClient.setMake(newClient.getMake());
        oldClient.setMileageType(newClient.getMileageType());
        oldClient.setModel(newClient.getModel());
        oldClient.setNotes(newClient.getNotes());
        oldClient.setOpener(newClient.getOpener());
        oldClient.setPaymentMethod(newClient.getPaymentMethod());
        oldClient.setPhone1(newClient.getPhone1());
        oldClient.setPhone2(newClient.getPhone2());
        oldClient.setPostal(newClient.getPostal());
        oldClient.setPrice(newClient.getPrice());
        oldClient.setProvince(newClient.getProvince());
        oldClient.setRecording(newClient.getRecording());
        oldClient.setRefunded(newClient.getRefunded());
        oldClient.setRegFee(newClient.getRegFee());
        oldClient.setStatus(newClient.getStatus());
        oldClient.setTaxRate(newClient.getTaxRate());
        oldClient.setTrim(newClient.getTrim());
        oldClient.setVerifier(newClient.getVerifier());
        oldClient.setYear(newClient.getYear());
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
        return newClient.getId();
    }
}
```

this is for JavaSE.

see also:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62890/javase-client-is-this-how-to-get-a-new-jpa-entitymanager-each-time-dao

Comment: errm, you're creating an EMF for every call? Let's make it slow down? An EM per call fine, but not EMF

Comment: I wasn't doing that at first, but saw that some people do that.  I don't care about performance, just that it doesn't time out.  whether it takes five seconds or five minutes to connect doesn't matter.  I've had the EM as a field, same result.  Tried the class as a bean, same result....

Comment: if some people jump off a cliff, I wouldn't copy; just have a single EMF and cut out that particular pain. As for why something takes time, that's where you look in the LOG of your JPA provider and see what is happening

Comment: it doesn't take some time, it **never** completes **sometimes**.  Usually, works fine, sometimes it just hangs.  this is for a java se, which log are you referring to? it says "logged in", along those lines.

Comment: All JPA implementations have a log, where they write SQL to, and what they are doing. Only you know what you're using, so you consult the docs of your implementation and find the log

Comment: I'm looking at something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24186909/java-nullpointerexception-at-jpa-entitymanagerimpl-getactivepersistencecontext

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61317/discussion-between-thufir-and-billy-frost).

Comment: well, leaving the log aside, why would the connection time out?

Comment: Your "case" is NOTHING like the NPE in that linked question. You HAVE TO LOOK AT THE LOG to understand it (saying forget the log is saying I can't be bothered with such things). YOU are the only person who knows what your JPA implementation is so nobody can hazard a guess at possible reason - my crystal ball is out of action right now. And you have to firstly fix your code to have a single EMF, and have an EM per call (all of which need closing when finally finished with).

Comment: I just don't know how to turn on the logging at the moment, I'll look into it.  thank you.

Comment: @BillyFrost I included a log, but all it shows, to me, is that nothing happened.  I'll modify the class so that it doesn't create an emf each time, but, from experience, that won't change the behaviour.  it may or may not change the log.

Comment: If you have a connection issue, obtaining more EMFs or EMs will not resolve the problem and likely make it worse. You need to find out why you have the problem, and once you know, then work out what you can do to resolve or best mitigate it.  You haven't posted the timeout exception or the connection details which should be the first place to start.  As for logging settings, you seem to be using EclipseLink and might want to log at the FINEST level: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

Comment: The logs shows that you are using JDBC directly, so you might want to look at the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525903/how-to-reconnect-lost-connections-with-eclipselink and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119095/eclipselink-connection-pooling  They do not match what you are looking for exactly but hte docs referenced in answers will help understand EclipseLink connection pool settings.  You will need to check your driver options for setting you might use, as well as firewalls between you and the DB.

Comment: I've looked at those, and it's not either.  the `persistence.xml` creates several connections, still gets time-outs.  I don't see how it could be a firewall, since quitting and restarting the application allows new connections.  Something's wrong with how it persists, and possibly other methods -- which is why I reconnect each and every time (which "solves" the timeout problem).